# Synchronously executing long running methods in a Service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service, worker-thread

I have an android service that has a set of operations :

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public int login() {
      //Invokes yet another logic to initiate login and waits for result 
      //synchronously and returns status code based on result of operation
    }

    public int logout() {
      //Invokes yet another logic to initiate logout and waits for result 
      //synchronously and returns the status code
    }
}
```

I am invoking the methods from a client activity say, `MyClientActivity.java` residing in the same process.
For each operations the service invokes some logic and waits for the result in a synchronous manner. When the service is executing all of this logic I do not want the user to perform anything else and just show a loading screen. So basically, after I have initiated an operation I want `MyClientActivity` to wait for the status code synchronously. Now I know that I cannot block the UI thread to avoid ANR. 
How can I make this operation execute on a separate thread and then get the result back so that I can appropriately propagate the result back to the user by changing the UI based on this result.
I am pretty new to this and can't really grasp the concepts. If someone can explain along with an example that would be helpful.

Comment: use the callbacks/local broadcases/ EventBus library. So in activity you ask service to  perform the request, and then block the UI (with loading view). Then service performs operations asynchronously, and when the operation finishes - it calls some Activity method (callback), sends a local broadcast, which you receive in Activity, or sends the event, which you receive in Activity (EventBus lib). Then in Activity you unblock UI, and process the result

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar. I register a callback instance from `MyClientActivity` itself with `MyService` and the service can invoke success/failure method on this callback. `MyClientActivity` will have the logic to manipulate the UI in respective success/failure methods of the callback implementation. My doubt is why should I add all this complication and extra code when I don't exactly need asynchronous behavior. I wanted a solution without callbacks. Basically `MyClientActivity` should wait for result but on a worker thread instead of main UI thread to avoid ANR.

Comment: waiting for result on another thread is much more complicated then using callbacks, as well as you will any way have to pass something to notify the thread about operation finish.

Comment: Do you have any reference to an example of the implementation where the client waits for the result on a worker thread and then notifies the main thread ? I just want to analyze both the implementation models for the flexibility of adding more operations if needed in the future. I want to see how well both the models support potential operations with different requirements. Also I want to analyze how easily I can deal with edge cases in both models like crashing of a newly spawned process (spawned by `MyService`) where `MyService` may never be able to invoke the callback, etc.

Comment: I particularly needed references to implementations with thread manipulation because that is a new concept for me. Based on this I want to select an approach.

Comment: I don't have any, and I don't think enough people are using this approach to find some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by using a `HandlerThread` to create a `Handler` to which I am posting `Runnables` to do the background tasks.
To do that main thread tasks (UI tasks) I am using `mainLooper` to create another `Handler` to which I posts `Runnables` to do operations on views.
A rough representation of the code :

```
mBackgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do background operation in synchronous manner as usual.

    mMainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Remove loader, update UI
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android there are plenty ways to do **asynchronous** work like you desccribed. You can use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), a [Loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders), if you're using Retrofit library for network requests, than it has async requests built in, so follow the [documentation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests). Also, there is RxJava, but it's learning curve quite steep.